# Erro "No view found" fecha meu aplicativo

Tags: java, android

Estou criando um projeto com duas telas, uma com um botão e a outra com uma lista de números de telefone. Só que, quando clico no botão, aparece a mensagem de erro `"Unfortunately app has stopped"`.

**Minha MainActivity**

```
package com.example.babr;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    Button botao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       botao = (Button) this.findViewById (R.id.Botao01);
       botao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Segundo.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();


        }
    });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**Minha Segunda Activity**

```
package com.example.babr;

import com.example.babr.MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.os.Build;


public class Segundo extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.segundo);





        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**LogCat com o erro**

```
04-13 01:45:14.200: E/FragmentManager(768): No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.babr:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.200: E/FragmentManager(768): Activity state:
04-13 01:45:14.200: D/FragmentManager(768):   Local FragmentActivity 40d230c8 State:
04-13 01:45:14.220: D/FragmentManager(768):     mCreated=truemResumed=false mStopped=false mReallyStopped=false
04-13 01:45:14.220: D/FragmentManager(768):     mLoadersStarted=false
04-13 01:45:14.230: D/FragmentManager(768):   Active Fragments in 40d23330:
04-13 01:45:14.230: D/FragmentManager(768):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.230: D/FragmentManager(768):       mFragmentId=#7f05003c mContainerId=#7f05003c mTag=null
04-13 01:45:14.250: D/FragmentManager(768):       mState=0 mIndex=0 mWho=android:fragment:0 mBackStackNesting=0
04-13 01:45:14.250: D/FragmentManager(768):       mAdded=true mRemoving=false mResumed=false mFromLayout=false mInLayout=false
04-13 01:45:14.260: D/FragmentManager(768):       mHidden=false mDetached=false mMenuVisible=true mHasMenu=false
04-13 01:45:14.260: D/FragmentManager(768):       mRetainInstance=false mRetaining=false mUserVisibleHint=true
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):       mFragmentManager=FragmentManager{40d23330 in Segundo{40d230c8}}
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):       mActivity=com.example.babr.Segundo@40d230c8
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):   Added Fragments:
04-13 01:45:14.280: D/FragmentManager(768):     #0: PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.290: D/FragmentManager(768):   FragmentManager misc state:
04-13 01:45:14.290: D/FragmentManager(768):     mActivity=com.example.babr.Segundo@40d230c8
04-13 01:45:14.300: D/FragmentManager(768):     mContainer=android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$2@40d233a8
04-13 01:45:14.310: D/FragmentManager(768):     mCurState=2 mStateSaved=false mDestroyed=false
04-13 01:45:14.310: D/FragmentManager(768):   View Hierarchy:
04-13 01:45:14.330: D/FragmentManager(768):     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d248e8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.350: D/FragmentManager(768):       android.widget.LinearLayout{40d24fb0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.350: D/FragmentManager(768):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40d25b90 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020359 android:id/action_bar_container}
04-13 01:45:14.360: D/FragmentManager(768):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{40d26178 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102035a android:id/action_bar}
04-13 01:45:14.370: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.LinearLayout{40d272b0 V.....C. ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.370: D/FragmentManager(768):               com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{40d289b0 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.390: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d28e10 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up}
04-13 01:45:14.390: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d29190 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102002c android:id/home}
04-13 01:45:14.400: D/FragmentManager(768):               android.widget.LinearLayout{40d2aab0 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.400: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.ImageView{40d2ae98 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020246 android:id/up}
04-13 01:45:14.410: D/FragmentManager(768):                 android.widget.LinearLayout{40d2b220 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.420: D/FragmentManager(768):                   android.widget.TextView{40d2b610 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102024d android:id/action_bar_title}
04-13 01:45:14.440: D/FragmentManager(768):                   android.widget.TextView{40d2c340 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102024e android:id/action_bar_subtitle}
04-13 01:45:14.440: D/FragmentManager(768):           com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContextView{40d2c998 G.E..... ... 0,0-0,0 #102035b android:id/action_context_bar}
04-13 01:45:14.460: D/FragmentManager(768):         android.widget.FrameLayout{40d2cf10 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #1020002 android:id/content}
04-13 01:45:14.460: D/FragmentManager(768):           android.widget.RelativeLayout{40d2dfb8 V.E..... ... 0,0-0,0}
04-13 01:45:14.480: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.TextView{40d2e550 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050040 app:id/textView1}
04-13 01:45:14.480: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.TextView{40d2eb70 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050041 app:id/textView2}
04-13 01:45:14.480: D/FragmentManager(768):             android.widget.TextView{40d2f198 V.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #7f050042 app:id/textView3}
04-13 01:45:14.490: D/FragmentManager(768):         com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{40d2d390 G.ED.... ... 0,0-0,0 #102035c android:id/split_action_bar}
04-13 01:45:14.500: D/AndroidRuntime(768): Shutting down VM
04-13 01:45:14.520: W/dalvikvm(768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-13 01:45:14.540: D/dalvikvm(768): GC_CONCURRENT freed 205K, 12% free 2572K/2916K, paused 8ms+34ms, total 213ms
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.babr/com.example.babr.Segundo}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.babr:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.babr:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{40d2fbd0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
04-13 01:45:14.580: E/AndroidRuntime(768):  ... 11 more
04-13 01:45:17.000: I/Process(768): Sending signal. PID: 768 SIG: 9
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.babr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.babr.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.babr.Segundo"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN1" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

De uns tempos pra cá quando você tenta criar um projeto Android contendo uma `activity` no Eclipse ADT, este agora inclui um `fragment` junto com a `activity`. Para iniciantes, porém, considero muito complicado mexer com o ciclo de vida do `fragment` assim logo de cara. Portanto recomendo remover todo esse código referente a `fragment`, isto é, remover toda a classe `PlaceholderFragment` de dentro de `MainActivity`, remover também o arquivo `res/layout/fragment_main.xml` e também remover qualquer referência a `fragment` de dentro do arquivo `activity_main.xml`. Isso vai simplificar o seu projeto e provavelmente eliminar o erro que está acontecendo.